# Detect references to a method inside loops in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio, foreach, model

I'm working on a bad architect solution and one of the main problem is loops (foreach loop almost always) that invokes a certain method of the model, and that method do some query. It's not my code but now I'm working on it, I add a very simplified sample here:

```
List<Models.Client> clients = Models.Client.LoadByCity("New York");

foreach (client in clients) 
{
    client.ChangeCity("Los Angeles"); // Triggers a DB Query every iteration!!!
}
```

I have programmed (lots of...) new methods in the model in order to support a multiple query based on a list, so that foreach loops now just create a list instead of doing the query, and finally launch a unique query at the end, when possible.

The solution has about 200.000 lines of code (and growing...) and it is tedious for me to manually look for that situations. Usually I detect it while debugging other tasks and just fix it, but it has been a few months doing it and it never ends. Trust me if I tell you the database is almost collapsed and each day traffic are increasing, so it is like building a railway while the train is running on it.

My question: Is there any way, maybe a regex, maybe a plugin or a NuGet package that let me find references to methods inside of a certain loop or sequencer? It will be a lot easier for me to check references to single methods in that way than checking ALL references and its full Stack Call, that usually is a really long spaghetti.

[image: Medium size solution, too much code to manually find that issues]